# Car chugs along after jump start but no lights work

Tags: ford, battery, alternator, escape

Today I was leaving work and my car didn't start so I had it jumped by a coworker. I was driving on and noticed that my gauges weren't working and my lights weren't turning on. It also chugs along and sounds like the engine wants to die as well as didn't accelerate when stepped on the gas pedal. Made it home,  I don't know how,  and when I parked it it died in me.
It's a 2005 ford escape v6 2wd amd just two days ago bought a brand new battery so does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The new battery is flat.

Why is the next question. When you replaced the old battery did you have the charging system checked, or did you just replace the old battery as it was flat and you thought it was defective.

I suggest that you charge the new battery, once it is fully charged then you can check the alternator and make sure it is charging.

Comment: Yes I was late to work and just replaced it so didn't check my alternator or anything else. Going to get the battery charged up and then check it out at autozone or O'Reilly s

Answer (score 0):

I don't hope the person who jumped started the car used a calibrated 12V-14V output, if more your system could be burned, or partially... Sy son had a similar situation, at garage with problem, they tried to start it so many times the battery down, jump started and burned out the CPU on the carlights didn't work and a series of more problem.. Start up using a quick start-up machine could bring more problems,.. hope your are not having the same problem... could be interesting to check the output in Volts are in range..

Comment: Well the headlights did turn on when I have it in park but turn off when I turn the key to start but it was a simple jump start one try with cables so hopefully no problems